# How to write ODE to standard form?

Tags: differential-equations

Package like `odepack` needs the ODE written in standard form, which means write the high order ODE to first order ODE equations. The steps of converting ODE to standard form are quite standard, but I do not find functions in Mathematica that can rewrite high order ODE into its standard form. For example,

```
EQ = y''[x] + Sin[y[x]] y[x] == 0
```

The equation can somehow rewrite to

```
{D[y1[x],x] == - Sin[y0[x]] y0[x], D[y0[x],x] == y1[x]}
```

Comment: However, if one is using `NDSolve[]`, one does not actually need to perform the exercise of turning everything into a set of first order equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`NonlinearStateSpaceModel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearStateSpaceModel.html) and extract the ODE's from it if needed, or just read them from the result, or just use the state space formulation as is.

```
Clear[x, x1, x2, y]
eq = y''[x] + Sin[y[x]] y[x] == 0;
sys = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[eq, {{y'[x], 0}, {y[x], 0}}, {}, {y[x]}, x]
```

[image: result]

```
Normal[sys]
```

[image: the equations]

Notice that it uses those funny looking symbols with the little dot on them, but I think there is way to format these out. I remember Mr. Wizard had function on this site for doing something like this.

These above say that $x_{2}' = -\sin(x_1) x_1$ and $x_{1}' = x_2$

Comment: ref/character/FormalX